# Simple Linux IPC Question

Tags: c, linux, ipc

Currently I have a client process and a server process. The client process needs to contact the server process every so often to exchange data, but needs to know the server's pid to do so. How should the client know how to do this? I want to avoid repeated hard disk access. This application runs only under linux. Currently the server sets up a lock file with its pid which lives or a RAM disk. The client checks the file. How else can I accomplish this transaction efficiently such that the server can send a signal to the client? (note: client is PHP, server is c)

Comment: I was approaching this whole problem incorrectly, as others have suggested, HOWEVER: A convenient approach to do precisely what I wanted to do at the time (optimize repeated filesystem access) DOES exist! It is the tmpfs filesystem often mounted at /dev/shm. It may not be 100% portable across distributions but it seems to be fairly standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some ideas:

1. do nothing; if you repeatedly read it, reading a disc file (on a proper, permanent disc) will not cause any IO, because the file will already be in cache.
2. Refactor your system so you don't need to know the pid file
3. Are you sure that you really care? Premature optimisation and all that. How many times per second are you doing this, 1000 or more?

Answer (score 4):

I assume, when you say "process", these two are on the same machine? If so, you could use a named FIFO in the `/tmp` directory. This is an example of two processes using IPC with the named FIFO `/tmp/test.fifo` with `fork()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <linux/stat.h>

int errno;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char fifo_path[] = "/tmp/test.fifo";
    char buffer[128];

    int result = mkfifo(fifo_path, 0600);

    printf("mkfifo result = %d\n", result);

    if (errno == EEXIST)
        printf("errno == EEXIST\n");

    pid_t child = fork();

    if (child == 0)
    {
        printf("%d> child; opening fifo \"%s\" for writing\n", getpid(),
                 fifo_path);

        FILE* fifo = fopen(fifo_path, "w");
        char in_buffer[128];

        fgets(in_buffer, 128, stdin);

        fputs(in_buffer, fifo);

        fclose(fifo);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d> parent; opening fifo \"%s\" for reading\n", getpid(),
                 fifo_path);

        FILE* fifo = fopen(fifo_path, "r");

        fgets(buffer, 128, fifo);

        if (buffer[0] == EOF)
            printf("%d> got EOF\n", getpid());
        else
        {
            buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0;
            printf("%d> read string \"%s\"\n", getpid(), buffer);
        }

        fclose(fifo);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So as long as both processes know the full path of the FIFO, they can read and write to it.

Comment: This is what I already have going on, but the problem is synchronization. Currently my setup is to have client signal server that it is ready for a transaction, and then the transaction happens inside a signal handler function in the server. How do it know which pid to send the signal to?

Comment: You don't need to know a PID; you just need to know if the client is reading the FIFO. There is a way to do this; I'm not sure though. I believe the server will block when writing to the FIFO until it is opened for reading. You can make the FIFO with certain arguments which means the server will not block, but if it is not being read from, the server will receive the SIGPIPE signal. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you don't use the pid but an address of some sort - an IP address (including port), a Unix domain socket address, a path in the filesystem, or some higher-level IPC system built on top of one of these (D-Bus, X, etc.) to reach and communicate with a server. The only thing the pid would be useful for is sending a signal, which is probably a really bad way to communicate, and won't work if you separate your client and server into separate privilege domains.

Comment: Ok, ok, good, I like the sound of that, and I've already had to do some unpleasant things to get privs right, but if I implement this *how does my server know when the client has asked for something?* It needs to be doing one thing most of the time (collecting data for the client) and then when the client asks it needs to transmit. Right now a signal handler allows me to asynchronously execute code when a signal comes in. But with a socket... can I set up some sort of event handler for the socket? Should I fork and have one branch just loop listening the the socket?

Comment: There are two general approaches to this. One is to structure your server as an event loop using `select` (or `poll`) to wait for input from any one of a number of file descriptors, and possibly also wait for the ability to write output from your buffers. The other is to use threads or separate processes each blocking in IO. If you use processes though, you'll run into a problem of how to make them communicate and end up back at `select`. So I would either just use a `select` loop to begin with, or use threads (communicating with pthread primitives like condition variables and barriers).

Answer (score 1):

Some other options include:

1. Set up the server to listen on a specific port.
2. The server could set up a named pipe, and the client could communicate with it over that.

Comment: So... nobody is answering my question. My question isn't exactly about IPC. It is about synchronizing for IPC. I already have the client and server communicate over a named pipe. The question is how the server should know when to listen to the pipe. Right now that is accomplished with signals (hence the problem of knowing the server's pid and keeping it somewhere where repeated access to the information will not spam disk reads). Are you saying that instead off attempting synchronization the server should just listen for client communications on the pipe whenever it isn't doing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

- Unix Domain Sockets
- [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use name IPC message queue in non_blocking mode. I don't know whether named pipe supportes non_blocking mode or not but if it is then you can also use that. In non_block mode, you just register queue descriptor to signal and go into general wait. Your process will get awake if there is any activity on queue. Please do some search over internet and you can find many example doing the same.

To give correct/exact answer, i should be knowing your design of server process.